# serial port waiting for 13 bytes to be stored in the buffer

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have this piece of code:

```
public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {   
            int bytes = serial.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
            serial.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
            foreach (var item in buffer)
            {
                Console.Write(item.ToString());
            }
            Variables.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Variables.buffering);
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this)));
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();

        }
```

then I will send 13 bytes to the serial port. How will I modify this so that my program will wait for the buffer to become 13 bytes and if the buffer is 13 bytes, it should execute this one without an error:

```
Variables.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 

Additional information: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
```

Comment: If `BytesToRead` is < 13, don't read from the serial port. If there is, just read 13 bytes.

Comment: thanks. It helps alot. I did not get the error anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will receive the ArgumentException when the size of the byte array is less than 8.

The ToInt64 method is expecting a byte array which it can take at least 8 values from the starting index.

This is stated on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the method under the 'Exceptions' section.

An way to apply your 13 bytes test can be done as follows:

```
public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (serial.BytesToRead >= 13)
      {            
        byte[] buffer = new byte[13];
        serial.Read(buffer, 0, 13);
        foreach (var item in buffer)
        {
          Console.Write(item.ToString());
        }
        Variables.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Variables.buffering);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this)));
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Matt Burland's comment above is a more sensible approach.

Comment: See updated answer to include a suitable if statement, based on Matt Burland's comment